Reshaping a DataFrame using pandas
I have a DataFrame like this:
(a simplified example)



Col_1
Col_2




A01
123


A01
234


A01
345


A02
987


A02
876


B01
aaa



How could I transform into this?



A01
A02
B01




123
987
aaa


234
876
NaN


345
NaN
NaN



I've tried pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table() method, but there would be repeated values in the output DataFrame.

Check No.10 in Q/A
